# Sliding a div a second time resets it's position and only after that moves it

Tags: jquery

I have two buttons , the first one slides a div to the left , and the second button slides the same div right , at least it's supposed to...

```
 $('#homelink').click(function() {
  $('#hometable').animate({
    right: '-=500px'
  }, 500, function() {
  });
});
$('#projectslink').click(function() {
  $('#hometable').animate({
    left:'+=100%'
  }, 500, function() {
  });
});

<table id="hometable" style="position:relative; top:10%">
```

Now when the "projectslink" button is clicked , how do i get the "hometable" to slide FROM the position it was slid to by the first button , because what happens is , it first resets the table's original position and then slides it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what you are asking for , but i guess that is because you are changing the right position on first click and then changing left on other..change right for both and that should work..

```
$('#homelink').click(function() {
  $('#hometable').animate({
    right: '-=500px'
  }, 500, function() {
  });
});
$('#projectslink').click(function() {
 $('#hometable').animate({
   right:'+=500px'
 }, 500, function() {
});
});
```

Comment: Yes i think that was it because now it's working , and also i don't think i should use percentages... thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#projectslink').click(function () {
    $('#hometable').animate({
        left: '+=100%',
        right: '+=500px'
    }, 500, function () {});
});
```